# In replit i have a bot in the making with a secret for the token but its erroring and i dont how in any way how to fix it

Tags: discord.js, typeerror, replit, secret-key

heres the code (its just a bot i started making)
index.js

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Logged in!');
});

var TOKEN = process.env['YOUR_TOKEN_HERE']

client.login(TOKEN);
```

heres the error:
[image: the error message. im not gonna type the whole thing here because its too long]

the var TOKEN =... used to be const but i figured if i made it a var it would work. it did not and im not even sure what the error is about. other then that i just dont know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't up to date with the latest discord.js version which I assume you are on v14, refer to the official [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/). Alternatively, refer to the [discord.js documentation](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/ClientOptions) for ClientOptions, the arguments passed to the constructor (`new Discord.Client(`**`ClientOptions here`**`)`). This documentation specifies that the *`intents`* field is non-optional, which is specified in the error.

As such, you need to specify which intents you are using for example

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });
```